# ffmpeg burn chinese subtitle(srt) with error

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I use ffmpeg to add Chinese subtitles to the video. and the libass library has been installed.

I execute the following command and error messages will appear

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "ass=subtitle.srt" -y out.mp4
```

error message:

[image]

And the Chinese subtitles of the output video are unreadable.

[image]

So the question I want to ask is：

1. What caused this?
2. how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved! Need to install fonts**

Problem finding step:

a) find ffmpeg fontconfig

```
cat /opt/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig/fontconfig.pc
```

[image]

b) find fontconfig config file according to the path obtained above

```
cat /opt/ffmpeg/etc/fonts/fonts.conf
```

[image]

c) Put the required fonts into this folder `/usr/share/fonts/truetype`